# Limits of Gaussian error function

Tags: limits, improper-integrals, gaussian-integral

Show that $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \int_{1}^x e^{-y^2} dy$$
exist and is in $[e^{-4},1]$

I cannot find a good minoration, I must show it whitout using the double integration, I totally don't know how to solve it

Comment: What techniques have you learned? The decay rate here is pretty rapid, if that gives you any hints for existence! As for establishing the image, note that your integral is monotonically increasing toward $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\operatorname{erfc(1)} \approx 0.13940\ldots > 0.018315\ldots = e^{-4}$ which gives you almost an order of magnitude of wiggle-room to make this work. Accordingly, I would think any simple estimation technique should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Existence:** Note that $e^{-x^2} \le e^{-x}$ for all $x \in [1,\infty)$

---

**Bounds:** 
$$\begin{align}
\int_1^x e^{-t^2} dt &=\int_1^3 e^{-t^2} dt +\int_3^\infty e^{-t^2} dt\\
&<\int_1^3 e^{-t^2} dt +\int_3^\infty e^{-t} dt
\end{align}$$
Estimate the finite integral in your favorite manner, and the second integral is trivial. For tighter bounds replace $3$ with any larger real number.

Answer (score 2):

I have a funny answer, if you find Fourier transform without integrating fun. :D

Note that $e^{-y^2}$ is monotonically decreasing as $|y|\rightarrow\infty$ and that the function is always positive. That means 
\begin{equation}
0<\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}dy<\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}dy.
\end{equation}
If we find the value of the right integral and find that is indeed smaller than 1 and if we find a piece of area larger than $e^{-4}$ we are done. So let's do it!

I will give the function a name: $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\quad f(y)=e^{-y^2/2}$.

First note that the function is even $f(-y)=f(y)$, so $$\ \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(y)dy=2\ \int_{0}^{\infty}f(y)dy.$$
With the Fourier transform (=FT) of it (which exists because it is a function of Schwarz space) $$\tilde{f}(k)=F(f)(k)=a\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(y)e^{-iky}dy$$
and the inverse Fourier transform of it
$$f(x)=F^{-1}\left(\tilde{f}\right)(x)=a\int_{\mathbb{R}}\tilde{f}(k)e^{iky}dk$$ where $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$. OK, let's note that $$f'(y)=-yf(y).$$ We know that $\tilde{f}(k)$ exists. So let me calculate, weirdly enough its derivative
$$
\frac{d}{dk}\tilde{f}(k)=\frac{d}{dk}a\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(y)e^{-iky}dy=a\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\partial}{\partial k}f(y)e^{-iky}dy=a\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(y)e^{-iky}(-iy)dy=(*).
$$
From the differential equation above we substitute to get $f'(y)$ in the integrand:$$
(*)=ai\int_{\mathbb{R}}f'(y)e^{-iky}dy.
$$
Now with the product rule/parital integration we get$$
(*)=ai\left(f(y)e^{-iky}\vert_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y)e^{-iky}(-ik)dy\right)=-k\tilde{f}(k)$$ There! The FT of $f$ satisfies the same linear differential equation as $f$. So we can conclude that $f=\tilde{f}$. I.e. $$\tilde{f}(k)=e^{-k^2/2}$$ If you are pedantic, you would say the integration constant of the solution to $$\tilde{f}'(k)=-k\tilde{f}(k)$$ has nothing to do with the FT. That's true but with the inverse FT, you will see the constant is 1. Luckily, I am not pedantic.

Moving on, let's calculate the integral using $u=\sqrt{2}y$ substitution
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}dy=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-y^2}dy=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-u^2/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}du=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-u^2/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{-i0u}du=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\tilde{f}(0)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}<1.
$$
Now let's vertify the lower bound is still $\geq e^{-4}$: The rectangle with length 1 and height $e^{-4}$ fits underneath the graph of $e^{-y^2}$ for $y\in[1,2],$ so $$
e^{-4}<\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}dy<1.
$$